# Find the function $ f$: $\mathbb R^+$ $\to$ $\mathbb R^+$ satisfying: $ f(2f(x)+2y) = f(2x+y) +y $

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find the function $f : \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ satisfying: $f(2f(x) + 2y) = f(2x+y) + y.$

I think this problem is difficult in the set of determination and the set of values. If the deterministic set is $\mathbb R$, we can easily solve the problem:

Choose $y = 2x - 2f(x)$

$\Rightarrow 2f(x)+2y = 2x+y $

$\Rightarrow f(2f(x)+2y) = f(2x+y)$

$\Rightarrow y= 0$

$\Rightarrow f(x)=x$ (Try again and see if it is correct.)

That's all I did. I hope to get help from everyone. Thank you very much.

Comment: See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2299898p18182024). The issue in your attemp is that setting $y=2x-2f(x)$ presumes that $x>f(x)$.

Comment: @Sadd Yes , so is x > f(x) always true ? And how to prove it?

Comment: It is not clear how to prove that $x \geq f(x) $ for all $x$, although the guess $f(x)=x$ shows that there is some truth to it. You should probably look to try something else. Have you worked with functional equations before? There are some common techniques that are in place, for example, you might try to show that $f$ is injective, or that $f$ in increasing. Since $f(x)=x$ has both these properties, you could try to prove these properties first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(2f(x) + 2y) = f(2x+y) + y$

Assuming that $f ( a ) = f (b)$
$\Rightarrow$ $ f(2a+b) = f(2b+y)$

If $ a {\neq} b {\Rightarrow} $ f is a periodic function with period s.

Notation P(a;b) : Replace x by a, y by b into the original equation .

$P(x;y+s)$ and $P(x;y)$  $\Rightarrow$ $s=0$  $\Rightarrow$ $a=b$

$P(x;y-f(x)+f(t))$   $\Rightarrow$ $f(2y+2f(t)) = f(2x+y-f(x)+f(t)) +y-f(x)+f(t) $

$\Rightarrow$ $f(2t+y) + y = f(2x+y-f(x) + f(t)) + y- f(x) + f(t) $

Set $2t-2x+f(x)-f(t) =s $

$\Rightarrow$ $( 2t+y)-(2x+y-f(x)+f(t)) =s $

Replace $y$ by $ 2x+y-f(x)+f(t)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(y+s) +f(x) - f(t) = f(y) $.

Set $ f(x) - f(t) = r$

$\Rightarrow$ $f(y+s) +r = f(y)$

$\Rightarrow$ $f(2f(x)+2y)-r = f(2f(x)+2y+s) $

$\Rightarrow$ $f(2f(x)+2y)-2r = f(2f(x)+2y+2s) $

In a similar way we have $ f(2f(x)+2y)-2r = f(2f(x)+2y-2r)$

$\Rightarrow$  $2f(x)+2y+2s = 2f(x)+2y-2r$

$\Rightarrow$  $ s=-r $

$\Rightarrow$  $ 2t-2x+f(x)- f(t) = -f(x)+f(t) $

$\Rightarrow$ $f(x)-x = f(t)-t = C $

$\Rightarrow$ $f(x) = x+C $

It is easy to see that $C = 0$. $\Rightarrow$ $f(x) = x$